# Can't add user to docker group

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usergroups

I'm trying to set docker up on a new system, and when running docker info I get:

```
docker -v
=> Docker version 18.09.5, build e8ff056

docker info
=> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
   socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/info: dial unix 
   /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Following the docs, I've tried:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

Which returns no output. When I then run groups:

```
groups
=> mark adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

I can see a docker group exists:

```
less /etc/group | grep docker
=> docker:x:131:mark
```

And can see that it owns a socket running where the error message states:

```
ls -la /var/run/ | grep docker
=> 
drwx------  5 root                root                 120 May 25 14:54 docker
-rw-r--r--  1 root                root                   5 May 25 14:54 docker.pid
srw-rw----  1 root                docker                 0 May 25 14:54 docker.sock
```

So why can't I add myself to that group with `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER` ?

Comment: I believe you need to login/restart for the changes to be completed.

Comment: Your belief is correct, thanks!

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, in my case, "login/restart" literally meant I needed to *_reboot_* for the changes to take effect, not merely restart the bash session. Wowzers.

Comment: One gotcha to watch for is that you run `groups` to check if you've been added to the docker group whereas you probably need to run `groups $USER`. This is since according to `man groups` "if no USERNAME is specified, [groups will display groups] for the current process (which may differ if the groups database has changed)"

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to reload your shell in order to make the changes take effect.
Often you need to reboot your shell process and possibly even restart your computer.

e.g

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
sudo reboot
```

See @4Z4T4R answer and give a thumbs
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66297855/7961500

#### Load changes without quitting your shell

To avoid starting a new shell you can run. (Doesn't seem to work for all environments)

`exec su -l $USER`

This will create a new subshell with the loaded changes and replace your current shell with it.

#### If you need it to work now without restarting your computer

Another way if you just need to get it working now, is to change your primary group. This is only a temp solution as with any new shell you will need to apply it again.

```
export my_group=$(id -gn)
newgrp docker
newgrp $my_group
```

### Documentation

You can also look at the offical documentation here
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: restarting the shell did not work for me, but `newgrp docker` did. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Same issue here on ubuntu 20.04, `newgrp docker` seemed to work for me.  `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER` seemed to work periodically, but after reboot the group was lost.

Comment: Exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 19.10, for me only `newgrp docker` fixes it, but it's not persistent

Comment: The `newgrp` command is *very* different from `usermod -aG GROUP USER`: the latter *adds* group GROUP to USER, without changing the primary group of USER; the newgrp creates a new *shell* and in that shell, the USER's *primary* group changes to GROUP! This is not likely the desired effect: the OP still wants files created by USER to belong to user's primary GROUP, but wants files owned by GROUP to be accessible by USER. Very completely different.

Comment: That is true, I updated the post to help maintain the same behaviour. It is not the ideal way to solve this issue but is a final option if nothing else is working for you. At this point even the offical docker documentation suggests doing this. I added the link to the post.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, on Ubuntu 20.04, run `sudo reboot` after this command:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

I literally needed to **reboot** my operating system (and machine) for the change to take effect. Restarting/reloading the bash session did not apply the new setting.

Sure, `newgrp docker` does the trick "on the fly" without restart/reboot/re-anything... but once the session terminates, *POOF* you're not in the `docker` group any longer.

Added this as a formal answer bc it genuinely solved the OP's---and my (identical)---problem.

Credit should go to @Omari Celestine for the suggestion, but because I suck at interpretation, I (and maybe you) need the literal disambiguation that this answer provides.

Comment: I tried the usermod & reboot & doesn't work for me, the only thing working is `newgrp docker`

Answer (score 3):

Its a two step process technically. Run

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

then,

```
sg docker -c "bash"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the permissions on the /var/run/docker.sock file and restart docker process.

```
sudo chown jenkins:jenkins /var/run/docker.sock
sudo 644 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Then,

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Before running $docker info, Please make sure that the docker service up.

If not pls start the service by running below command.

$service docker start

Now you check the $docker info